# How to get latest GoogleMaps SDK using pods

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsautocomplete

1. I'm trying out the google places sdk sample. I installed it using

> pod try GoogleMaps

2. I installed GoogleMaps (1.10.5) using cocoapods

> source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
>
> platform :ios, '8.1'
>
> pod 'GoogleMaps'

checking the GoogleMaps in both steps, the one in the sample (1) contains more headers like GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource.h

[image]

Why are they different? The one in the sample seems to be a better version but the one given by pods is not the latest? Its not even in the [changelog](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleMaps#changelog)

Answer (score 9):

Run `pod update GoogleMaps`.  Cocoapods won't update the version of a pod you've already downloaded unless you explicitly run `pod update` or update the podspec to require a newer version.  See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html for more details.

Comment: I ran `pod update GoogleMaps`. This only updated the current version. But when I ran `pod update` then it upgraded from 2.2 to 2.3.0. But my xcode still reports that a newer version 2.3.3 exists. I think I'll run `pop update GoogleMaps` again.

Answer (score 4):

I checked the latest [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/a/d/d/GoogleMaps)

I just need to set the version to the latest

> e.g
>
> pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2.5.0'

Answer (score 0):

In my project's podfile, I don't specify the version. The pod line just specifies: pod 'GoogleMaps'

So, if you don't include the version in the podfile, then the following command in a Terminal window will update to the latest version: pod 'GoogleMaps'

Please ensure the you are in the correct folder containing your podfile before entering this command.

It may take a while for Pod to process when you see this message: Updating local specs repositories.

Be patient - it took about 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this error, and I updated to latest GoogleMaps per the advice above, but had to delete the app on my device and install fresh for it to resolve the error. Error was still present until I did that.