# Cannot find protocol declaration for 'GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate'?

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I am going to display autocomplete city using google API.

I am following this https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete)
 doc. for implantation

but when I have tried to confirm that protocol then I got following error.
Cannot find protocol declaration for 'GMSAutocompleteViewControllerDelegate'?

Appreciate for help.

Comment: Perhaps you have an older version of the pod?  Try `pod update GoogleMaps`.  (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34645528/806600)

Comment: @spiv I have updated google map , using po update still it is not working, now I have googlemap 1.11.1 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem

$(inherited) add in framework search path.

- Add following in header search path.

$(inherited)

"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public"

"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps"

"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps"

Comment: Thanks for sharing how you fixed it.